# setlocale with error LNK2019

Tags: c++, c, setlocale

I'm trying to use setlocale function in a project for PocketPC 2003. Before this I made some simple tests replacing some chars in a separate Console application project. In the comsole application project function works very fine, no problem with her.

Usign the very same function for first project I have some problems. Inserting `<clocale>` I have the following errors:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
error C2059: syntax error : ':'
```

Changing `<clocale>` to `<locale.h>` I have linkage errors:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_setlocale referenced FILE: Utils.obj
fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals Pocket PC 2003
```

`<locale.h>` and `<clocale>` doesn't have lib files associated with that. In this case what's going on?

Comment: Maybe try wrapping the `#include` with `extern "C" {` `}`?

Comment: @Drew Understood. You were right. Wrapping include file now I get another error: error C2059: syntax error : 'string'. I've changed the file extension for cpp and problem remains.

Comment: Show us the code please.

Comment: #ifndef _UTIL_H_
#define _UTIL_H_


#include "library.h"
#include "Util.h"

#include <stdlib.h>

extern "C"{
 #include <locale.h>
} ... The rest is the definition of functions. And the file name is Util.cpp

Answer (score 1):

You are facing a C vs C++ linkage issue. C and C++ have very different way of mangling linkage name.

In order to tell your C++ compiler that the headers is supposed to have C mangling style you should add the following code:

```
extern "C" {
    // Some C code, headers inclusion etc...
}
```

You can learn more by googling what is linkage and mangling in C/C++.

Comment: Ok. Wrapping include file now I get another error: error C2059: syntax error : 'string'. I've changed the file extension for cpp and problem remains. I have stdio.h in my file. Inserting before the extern the previous problem occur. Inserting after I have the same error plus others related to FILE*, fp

Comment: Please provide more info on the syntax error. Give us where exactly. Have you try to use the `#include <locale>`. But anyway if you are using C++ you should use the `#include <locale>` and fix your syntaxe error

Comment: I'll try. <locale> doesn't exist in the include directory of PocketPC. The files are <clocale> and <locale.h>. This is how I use extern "C"{
 #include <cstdlib>
 #include <clocale>
}
These are the error produced:
error C2059: syntax error : 'string'
error C2065: 'FILE' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'fp' : undeclared identifier
error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value
error C2065: 'fp' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'fp' : undeclared identifier

Is there any information that needs to be provided?

Comment: ok forget about the extern since you are in C++. Can you tell us more about the error when using `<clocale>`?

Comment: Right. The file that contains these headers is being compiled as C file. I made some changes and now these errors are ocurring:
error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before ':'
error C2059: syntax error : ':'
I have 500 errors all of them of the mentioned types above. These errors occurs in both files(clocale and cstdlib). Searching in the files the errors points out for instructions like this:
using ::strtoul; using ::wcstombs;
I thinkit is related to STL. All of these instruction are inside _STD_BEGIN and _STD_END